# Proving $\exists k \in \mathbb{Z}: \forall l \in \mathbb{Z}: \lnot(k \mid l) $?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

$$\exists k \in \mathbb{Z}: \forall l \in \mathbb{Z}: \lnot(k \mid l) $$

I have no idea how to approach this problem? If true, prove it, and if false prove the the negation. With its negation being:

$$\forall k \in \mathbb{Z}:\exists l \in \mathbb{Z}: k \mid l$$

My intuition is telling me the negation is true, because for any k we can just choose k for l and then we get $k \mid k$, which is always true for the integers.

But then, I believe the orginal statement is also true. Because clearly, $ 0 \mid l $ only for $l = 0$. So, $$\forall l \in \mathbb{Z}: \lnot(0 \mid l)$$

Any suggestions of where I am going wrong?

Comment: You go wrong after "But then". You first say that $0 | 0$, but then say that $\forall l \in \mathbb{Z}: \lnot(0|l)$. These statements are not compatible.

Comment: Oh so your saying that since $\exists l\in \mathbb{Z}: 0 \mid l.$ We cannot conclude $\forall l \in Z: \lnot (0 \mid l)$

Answer (score 1):

According to the general [**definition of divisor**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor#Definition) the negation is always true assuming $l=mk$ and the original statement is not true.

Comment: If we let the definition of "k divides l" be: $$\exists n \in \mathbb{Z} : l = k \times n$$ then the negation statement works for $0$, no?

Comment: @FefnirWilhelm Yes you are right, with reference to the general definition the negation is true.